# What is the default weight in the output layer in the MLP?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have written two versions of the program one is with weight in last output layer and one without setting. Can you please suggest the weight program takes in case it is not explicitly mentioned in the **hidden and output** layers?

Code Snippet  - Version 1

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units = 6, kernel_initializer = "GlorotUniform",activation='relu',input_dim = 6))     #First layer
model.add(Dense(units = 6, kernel_initializer = "GlorotUniform",activation='relu'))  # Second hidden layer
model.add(Dense(units = 1,kernel_initializer = "GlorotUniform"))   # Output layer
```

Code Snippet  - Version 2

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units = 6, kernel_initializer = "GlorotUniform",activation='relu',input_dim = 6))     #First layer
model.add(Dense(units = 6, kernel_initializer = "GlorotUniform",activation='relu'))  # Second hidden layer
model.add(Dense(units = 1))   # Output layer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default weight initializer in TensorFlow Dense layer is **glorot_uniform**.
Therefore even if you don't explicitly mention it, it will use **glorot_uniform**.

Check the documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dense)